# SQL Query without duplicates

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables like this:

Names:

```
ID(K)   Name
--------------
1        n1
2        n2
```

Jobs:

```
ID      Job
------------
1        j1
1        j2
```

Phones:

```
ID      Phone
--------------
1        p1
1        p2
1        p3
1        p4
```

I'm doing a SELECT with LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT Names.Name, Jobs.Job, Phones.Phone
FROM
   Names LEFT OUTER JOIN Jobs ON Jobs.ID = Names.ID 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Phones ON Phones.ID = Names.ID
```

and returns:

```
n1   j1   p1
n1   j1   p2
n1   j1   p3
n1   j1   p4
n1   j2   p1
n1   j2   p2
n1   j2   p3
n1   j2   p4
n2  null null
```

but i need this results:

```
n1   j1   p1
n1   j2   p2
n1  null  p3
n1  null  p4
n2  null null
```

what's the solution?

Comment: What would be the reason that p3/p4 should be linked to n1, not n2?

Comment: There are no duplicates in your results.

Comment: How relates phones with names and jobs?

Comment: This is why I *discourage* using `id` as a column name. Consider using `nameId` (or whatever is more appropriate), such that the "goal" can be deciphered easily.

Comment: I tried your query, it just produced 3 rows of results: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f027/1

Comment: sry for typed mistakes, Edited! check table phones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not specifying which RDBMS, but this query works on at least SQL Server, PostgreSQL and Oracle. There may be a smarter analytic function to do this, but it escapes me at the moment.

```
WITH pjobs AS (
  SELECT id, job, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY   job) rn FROM jobs
), pphones AS (
  SELECT id, phone, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY phone) rn FROM phones
)
SELECT name, job, phone
FROM pjobs FULL JOIN pphones ON pjobs.rn = pphones.rn AND pjobs.id = pphones.id
RIGHT JOIN names ON names.id = pjobs.id OR names.id = pphones.id
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/259f6/1).